# Implementing numpy.linalg.norm for awkward-arrays

Tags: awkward-array

At the moment, no implementation exists for numpy.linalg.norm with akward-arrays.
In awkward1 I can use `behavior` to overwrite (or add?) implementations as shown in the tutorial.
In my use-case I have successfully implemented versions of `np.absolute` and `np.subtract` for `TVector2` and `TVector3` using the tutorial example. However, `numpy.linalg.norm` fails.

How can I define a behavior for awkward-arrays? E.g. in the example below I tried this with a simple int64 array:

```py
import awkward1 as ak
import numpy as np

def norm(data, *args, **kwargs):
    return np.absolute(data)

ak.behavior[np.linalg.norm, "int64"] = norm

sample = ak.Array(np.arange(10))

print(ak.type(sample))  # 10 * int64
print(np.absolute(sample))  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(np.linalg.norm(np.arange(10)))  # 16.881943016134134
print(np.linalg.norm(sample)) # raises TypeError
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ak.behavior.html , it's the place to start.

If `np.linalg.norm` is a ufunc, the following should work:

```
ak.behavior[np.linalg.norm, "vector2"] = lambda a: np.sqrt(a.x**2 +a.y**2)
```

where the data are in records with fields `x` and `y` that are named `"vector2"`. You can make such a thing with

```
ak.zip({"x": x_array, "y": y_array}, with_name="vector2")
```

(Caveat: I haven't tested this—I wrote it on my phone. I'll test it later and edit this answer, or you might be able to edit it.)

If it's not a ufunc, then there isn't a publicly accessible (i.e. no underscores) way to define it, and perhaps there should be.

Also, be aware of the https://github.com/scikit-hep/vector project, which is defining operations like this.

---

**Edit:** Looking at the [np.linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) documentation, you're right, it's not a ufunc. (`isinstance(np.linalg.norm, np.ufunc)` is `False`.)

Also, this function makes some strong assumptions about its input. Two-dimensional arrays are interpreted as matrices, rather than lists of vectors. In Awkward Array, such distinctions would be labeled by metadata. I don't think we *want* to implement a function like this, since it could wreak havoc on jagged arrays that are supposed to be lists of different length vectors.

I think what you want is to [add vector behaviors](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ak.behavior.html), like this:

```py
>>> class Vector2(ak.Record):
...     @property
...     def norm(self):
...         return np.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
... 
>>> class ArrayOfVector2(ak.Array):
...     @property
...     def norm(self):
...         return np.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)
... 
>>> ak.behavior["vector2"] = Vector2
>>> ak.behavior["*", "vector2"] = ArrayOfVector2
```

This just says that if you have a record that is *named* `"vector2"`, then it should be presented as Python class `Vector2`, and if you have an array (any depth) of `"vector2"` records, they should collectively be presented as an `ArrayOfVector2` class.

```py
>>> x_array = ak.Array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [], [4.4, 5.5]])
>>> y_array = ak.Array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [], [4.0, 5.0]])
>>> vectors = ak.zip({"x": x_array, "y": y_array}, with_name="vector2")
>>> vectors[0, 0]
<Vector2 {x: 1.1, y: 1} type='vector2["x": float64, "y": float64]'>
>>> vectors
<ArrayOfVector2 [[{x: 1.1, y: 1}, ... y: 5}]] type='3 * var * vector2["x...'>
```

That lets you use the methods and properties you've defined:

```py
>>> vectors[0, 0].norm
1.4866068747318506
>>> vectors.norm
<Array [[1.49, 2.97, 4.46], ... [5.95, 7.43]] type='3 * var * float64'>
```

But also, this is exactly what the https://github.com/scikit-hep/vector project is doing. Keep an eye on it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that `np.linalg.norm` is not a ufunc, at least I could not find any info that it is. I guess a way around it would be to implement a custom reduction instead.